# Accent portugais

Tags: accents-étrangers

Je lis présentement le roman *Sally Jones* à ma fille, et le début du roman se passe à Lisbonne. Les protagonistes viennent d'un peu partout à travers l'Europe et je désire mimiquer les accents. Il y a beaucoup de lusophones en ce début de roman et quoique je connaisse un peu de portugais et aie à peu près la sonorité de cette langue dans ma tête, j'ai un peu de difficulté à imiter un accent portugais en français, parce que je n'ai jamais entendu de portugais s'exprimer en français ou en anglais.

Je sais qu'ils grasseyent un peu les R, de façon un peu moins prononcé que les francophones. S'expriment-ils de façon particulière en français à cause de cette différence?

Le portugais possède de nombreuses nasales. Leurs voyelles nasales incluent cependant souvent la prononciation du N à leur suite. Ont-ils tendance à faire la même chose en français?

Le digraphe «un», le prononcent-ils /ũ/ ou /œ̃/ selon la prononciation française standard? Même question pour «in» (/ĩ/ ou /ɛ̃/?).

Nos É [e] et Ê [ε] ont les valeurs exactement inverses en portugais. Y a-t-il confusion pour ceux qui apprennent le français?

À l’oreille, je crois que les L sont rétroflexes (comme ceux de l’anglais). Pourrait-on me confirmer?

Et les E muets à la fin des mots, ont-ils tendance à les prononcer, et à les changer en I?

TI et DI deviennent-ils TCHI et DJI?

Y a-t-il aussi autre chose que j’oublie?

Comment: Leonardo Jardim: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovNuSgcyQOg

Comment: On bon début. J'y ai bien entendu /vɛ̃dʁədi/ et quelques /ũ/ ajustés en /œ̃/, après un très court délai. Pas de E muets inutiles et un bon sens des sons É et È. Quelques L à tendance rétroflexe, mais la plupart à la française.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les premières choses qui me viennent à l'esprit quand je pense à l'accent portugais:

- Une prosodie caractéristique, plus chantante que le français.
- Un allongement beaucoup plus prononcé des syllabes accentuées.
- Une prononciation chuintée: les *s* intérieurs prononcés *ch*; les *z* prononcés *j*; l'ajout de *ch* en fin de mot, à la place d'un *s* final muet (pays -> pa-iche) ou d'un *e* muet après certaines consonnes (tomate -> tomatch)
- Les voyelles nasales finales allongées avec un *w* voyelle (pain -> pão)
- La prononciation du *u* et des *e* en *ou* (du -> dou, le -> lou)
- Les L finaux prononcés comme un *w* voyelle (comment tu t'appelles -> commen-w tou toupe-w)

Il y a un comédien français d'origine portugaise qui fait des vidéos où il caricature cet accent à l'extrême https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCR9yS9fdNs

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Le comédien a un ton un peu surexcité qui ne conviendra guère à ma lecture, mais il est très expressif et joue beaucoup avec son accent, ce qui donne une bonne banque de sonorités dans laquelle piger.

Comment: Oui, il a aussi un registre de langage très vulgaire. Mais bon tu fais la moitié de ce qu'il fait et voilà :-)

Comment: Merci encore pour le surplus d’info. Ça semble assez en ligne avec ce que je connais de la langue, mais comme je le disais, je connais le portugais en VO seulement. Pour les voyelles avant les L, je suis curieux pour en plein mot: diraient-ils par exemple /pawto/ pour _paletot_? Parce que j’entends /awgũ/ pour _algum_ en portugais (du Brésil).

Comment: Si le L est en fin de syllabe à l'intérieur d'un mot, il peut tendre à être remplacé par un w, mais sinon il est prononcé normalement. Par exemple dans *je vais aller* le son L resterait prononcé comme un L. Paletot ça dépend si on prononce le E...